# Why are Maggie and Sharon so bitter and angry?

Tags: character-analysis, stephenie-meyer, the-host

In *The Host*, Melanie's aunt Maggie and her daughter Sharon, who Melanie was trying to find when she got caught by the souls and tried to jump down an elevator shaft, are shown to be quite bitter and angry - never really interacting with Wanderer and always keeping a distance from everyone... except when there's an argument when Kyle brings Sunny to the caves.

Do we know why they are so bitter?